# How to disable the "do you want to open or save" dialog in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, internet-explorer-10

We have some clients whom are complaining that in **IE10 metro-browser** on **Windows 8** they are prompted to either open or save **PDF** files which are referenced by links.
Once they click the open option, the **PDF** file opens in the default application (**Microsoft Reader**), but they really don't like the extra step.

I know that Microsoft has made the decision to not allow any plugins for **IE10 metro-browser**, but is there a way (*through an IE setting or registry hack*) that will just launch any **pdf** file in its default application without prompting the user?

I don't see a real issue with this since the user has to do this themselves and it's not as if the website is forcing the launch of a file.

In the **non-metro-browser**, they can install the **adobe reader plugin** and it works as they expect (*opens a new tab/window with the **PDF** document*)... but they want it to work in the **metro-browser**.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, IE 10 doesn't have the option to disable the prompt. Since, IE 10 has been designed in this way for security reasons.